# Print ONNXRUNTIME::Graph without having Model

Tags: c++, onnx, onnxruntime

I'm working on new optimizer that inherits from *GraphTransformer* in c++

How can I view the changes that I made, just after *ApplyImpl* ends
I tried *graph.ToGraphProto()* but I cannot save it 
And I need to make a new *Model* to be able to save it and view it in Netron or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it 
Need to make new model and versions
need to get SchemaRegistry:

```
ModelProto model_proto1;
model_proto1.set_ir_version(IR_VERSION);
OperatorSetIdProto* op_set_id = model_proto1.add_opset_import();
op_set_id->set_domain("");
op_set_id->set_version(12);
model_proto1.set_allocated_graph(new GraphProto(graph.ToGraphProto()));
IOnnxRuntimeOpSchemaRegistryList local_registries{graph.GetSchemaRegistry()};


Model model(model_proto1, &local_registries, logger);
onnxruntime::Model::Save(model, "/tmp/new_g.onnx");
```